# How often should I wax my bass?

Tags: maintenance, bass-guitar

When I bought my bass, it came with a surface finisher (beeswax). I've been waxing my bass about once every month/month and a half.

Why should I wax my bass and how often is it recommended I do it?

Comment: Are you sure you have a bass guitar (tag) and not a double-bass ? In 50 odd years of playing in bands, I've never come across a bass guitarist who waxed his guitar.

Comment: Actually? No, this isn't about my double bass, it's about my electric six-string bass

Comment: If you're talking about the body,and neck, which probably have either a polyurethane or cellulose paint job, it's hardly needed. The fingerboard may be a different point, as it's almost certainly raw wood, which could just need a rub down with lemon or such like, to take away the grease/sweat from your fingers.

Comment: What model is this? Like @Tim says, most electric basses shouldn't need this treatment.

Comment: It's a Warwick NT Thumb 6

Comment: Depends how fast the hair grows! <runs and hides>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having done some homework, your bass has no lacquer or paint as a finish - it's natural wood. As such, every couple of months it needs a feed/clean and beeswax is the stuff. Not heavily applied, and well rubbed off after, it puts a barrier on to help stop sweat etc., being absorbed into the wood. If you like a well-used look to your guitar, don't bother.(relic'd is in right now !) but to keep it pristine it needs the treatment. Apparently the instructions should have come with the new bass.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.warwick.de/warwick/data/Warwick.de/Technical%20PDF/Manuals/WWBassManual_en_2013.pdf:

> Natural Oil Finish:
>   Here you can use the included beeswax. Apply the beeswax with a polishing cloth using circular movements. After applying, wait 2 to 3 minutes and then remove the excess with a dry polishing cloth. The beeswax should be applied a minimum of two times per year, more depending on how frequently theinstrument is played. A more frequent application of beeswax will keep your instrument looking great, as it ages over time.

Answer (score 1):

Tim is right. It's just cosmetic - if you like the look, fine. But I have basses that have seen decades of frequent use that I haven't polished and they're fine.

Guitar repair people will tell you different, I imagine. But they earn their money that way.

Comment: I do not agree. Warwick builds expensive basses with a lot of attention to the woodwork. You should keep the surface of the wood sealed (especially the neck) to prevent deformation of the wood due to humidity changes .